# React-native bridging with Swift singleton custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

Today, I try to use my custom Swift class implementing Singleton pattern in my Javascript code. I already created native modules but today I've got this error : "**Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class**"

I guess it's because the Singleton pattern but I can't understand my mistake ...

Here's my code:

```
AnalyticsTracker.swift

import Foundation
import Tracker


@objc(AnalyticsTracker)
class AnalyticsTracker: NSObject {


  static let shared = AnalyticsTracker(tracker: ATInternet.sharedInstance.defaultTracker)

  // MARK: -

  let tracker: Tracker

  // Initialization

  private init(tracker: Tracker) {
    self.tracker = tracker
  }

  @objc
  func viewScreen(screen: String) {
    self.tracker.screens.add(screen).sendView()
  }

  @objc
  func sendTouch(clickName: String, chapter1: String, chapter2: String, chapter3: String, level2: Int) {
    let gesture = self.tracker.gestures.add(clickName, chapter1: chapter1, chapter2: chapter2, chapter3:chapter3)
    gesture.level2 = level2
    gesture.sendTouch()
  }
}
```

And the module to export my class to my react-native application :

```
AnalyticsTracker.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(AnalyticsTracker, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(
                  sendTouch:
                  (NSString*)clickName
                  (NSString*)chapter1
                  (NSString*)chapter2
                  (NSString*)chapter3
                  (int)level2
)

@end
```

The error disappear when I remove the export module. I really don't understand what the error mean ...

If someone have an idea it would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Did you found the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the React Native bridging mechanics. AFAIK it doesn't support a custom initialization. As a workaround you can create a helper class that would use AnalyticsTracker.shared in its exported methods:

```
// RNAnalyticsTracker.swift

import Foundation

@objc(RNAnalyticsTracker)
class RNAnalyticsTracker: NSObject {

  @objc
  func viewScreen(screen: String) {
    AnalyticsTracker.shared.viewScreen(screen: screen)
  }

  @objc
  func sendTouch(clickName: String, chapter1: String, chapter2: String, chapter3: String, level2: Int) {
    AnalyticsTracker.shared.sendTouch(clickName: clickName, chapter1: chapter1, chapter2: chapter2, chapter3: chapter3, level2: level2)
  }
}
```

Source reference: https://gist.github.com/harveyconnor/7b0e778effaae302f512485c18881569

Comment: Thank you ... That seems to be the only way forward ... Can you please also tell me how can pass Callback from Swift to reactNative ? My Swift code is in separate cocoapods private framework so the function inside swift cannot take RCTResponseSenderBlock as argument ... That is the only missing puzzle now ... Thank you for your help

Comment: @MihirMehta You can achieve that using the same technique. Just create a helper class with `@objc` methods, taking  RCTResponseSenderBlock as a parameter. And redirect the calls to you library class.

Comment: Thank you RCTResponseSenderBlock cannot be added as parameter as Cocoapods SDK is pure Swift library that i am building

Answer (score 0):

you are inheriting NSObject, so you have to provide the public init constructor, which would initialize your `tracker` property.

Comment: @MihirMehta, you're absolutely right. Sorry for misleading answer I'll add another one which hopefully would be useful for you.